# Is there an inclusion of $L_\infty(G)$ into $C_0(G)^{**}$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, measure-theory

This is probably a silly question with which I am stuck however. Let $G$ be a locally compact group. It seems to me that there is a canonical map of $L_\infty(G)$ into $M=C_0(G)^{**}$ (the latter is the enveloping von Neumann algebra of $C_0(G)$). I would reason as follows:

1. Let $I$ be the annihilator of $L_1(G)$ in $M$. Then a) $I$ is weakly closed (obvious); b) $I$ is an ideal. To prove the second thing, consider the quotient map $Q: M\to L_1(G)^*$. If we identify $L_1(G)^*$ with $L_\infty(G)$, then $Q$ becomes a homomorphism (it is a homomorphism on $C_0(G)$, and is weakly continuous). So the kernel of $Q$ is an ideal.
2. For every weakly closed ideal in a von Neumann algebra, there is a complementing ideal $J$ such that $M=I\oplus J$. (it is known that there is a central projection $p\in M$ such that $I=Mp=pM$, then put $J=(1-p)M$).
3. Now $M/I\simeq J\simeq L_\infty(G)$, so this isomorphism gives an inclusion in the title.

Why this worries me: since $C_0(G)^{**}$ is the dual space of $M(G)$, the space of Radon measures, then such an inclusion $T$ would mean that we can associate to every $f\in L_\infty(G)$ its value at every point of $G$, by $f(t)=Tf(\delta_t)$, where $\delta_t$ is the probability measure concentrated at $t$.

Am I doing a silly mistake? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I deleted a tentative answer-- your argument gives a *-homomorphism of $L^\infty(G)$ into $C_0(G)^{**}$, while I gave some more ``concrete'' arguments as to why this was plausible, they didn't seem to address why the "inclusion" would be an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: I was lucky to see it. I didn't insist that this inclusion is a homomorphism, just that it is continuous. Is your example continuous? Maybe you would post it again, at least as a comment?

Comment: Since you are in the commutative setting, you can present the construction more simply.  $M(G)= L_1(G)\oplus_1 S(G)$, where $S(G)$ is the space of complex measures that are singular with respect to Haar measure, and hence `$M(G)^*= L_\infty(G)\oplus_1 S(G)^*$`.

Comment: In some cases, you get a better embedding of $L_\infty(G)$ into $M(G)^*$ by first embedding $B(G)$, the bounded measurable functions under the sup norm, into `$M(G)^*$` in the obvious way and using the Tulcea lifting theorem (which applies e.g. if $G$ is sigma compact) to embed $L_\infty(G)$ into $B(G)$. This is better in that it extends the canonical embedding of $C_0(G)$ into its second dual. 

Well, I think this is right; I am going from memory rather than thinking through the argument. 

Comment: Ah, so if you follow Bill's first comment... then as each point mass $\delta_t$ lives in $S(G)$ (assuming $G$ has no discrete parts) then actually your way of "associating" a value at $t$ just always gives $0$ (and hence nothing to worry about, but also not very useful...)

Comment: @Bill: thank you, I would accept the comment on the direct sum if it were posted as an answer. As Matth points out, this $f(t)$ is 0, so nothing is contre-intuitive!

Comment: Right, but note that my second comment (if it is indeed correct) allows you to interpret pointwise evaluation of $L_\infty$ functions in many cases (e.g., when the group is metrizable).

Comment: @Bill: Your 1st comment explained to me what was the problem that bothered me, that's why I prefer this as an answer. Also I am interested in the general case. But: as I remember from Tulcea's book, there is a lifting on every l.c.group. It is a selector of measurable sets; would you please indicate how to transform this into a selector of $L_\infty$-functions?

Comment: The lifting gives a mapping from (indicator functions of) measurable sets modulo null sets to (indicator functions of) measurable sets; extend by linearity to a well defined mapping from the elements of $L_\infty$ that are simple modulo null sets to simple functions--this mapping is well defined, linear, and norm preserving, hence extends by continuity to a linear isometry from $L_\infty$ into $B(G)$.

Comment: Indeed, it is {\it norm-preserving}... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are in the commutative setting, you can present the construction more simply. $M(G)=L_1(G)\oplus_1 S(G)$, where $S(G)$ is the space of complex measures that are singular with respect to Haar measure, and hence $M(G)^∗=L_\infty (G)\oplus_\infty S(G)^∗$.

Answer (score 1):

**Undeleted:** This is perhaps a little more tangential to the original question than I'd hoped.  But maybe it gives some hints as to why the conclusions aren't that "worrying"...

I don't think this is silly.  For example, if $G=\mathbb R$ then for each $t\in\mathbb R$ consider $$ f_{t,n} = \frac{n}{2} \chi_{[t-1/n,t+1/n]} \in L^1(\mathbb R). $$
Then each $f_{t,n}$ is a unit vector in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.
Then given $F\in L^\infty(G)$, we define $$\tilde F(t) = \lim_n \langle F,f_{t,n} \rangle
= \lim_n \frac{n}{2} \int_{t-1/n}^{t+1/n} F(s) \ ds$$
Maybe this limit doesn't actually exist-- but the sequence is bounded, so just force it to converge via an ultra-filter limit, or similar.  I think you have just described an abstract version of this construction.  The point is that $\tilde F$ is little more than a function $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb C$ which is bounded; I don't see why it need have any continuity or measurability properties...

**Edit:** Actually, maybe a better argument is the following.  If you convolve an $L^1(G)$ function by an $L^\infty(G)$ function, then you get a (left or right, depending on taste) uniformly continuous function, which you can then integrate against a bounded measure.  So if $(e_\alpha)$ is a bai for $L^1(G)$, then define $T:L^\infty(G)\rightarrow M(G)^*$ by taking an ultrafilter limit: $\langle T(F),\mu\rangle = \lim_\alpha \int_G e_\alpha * F \ d\mu$.  This gives the identity on $C_0(G)$ (indeed, on left/right uniformly continuous functions).  I think this construction would be well-known to Banach algebraists...

Comment: Your edit looks right to me (although I'm not yet sufficiently caffeinated to be confident that I'm thinking straight) - I vaguely remember discussing a similar construction with MCW a while back, in a slightly different context with $L^\infty[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]^{**}$.

Comment: I like the second argument, and this shouldn't give zero for all $f$. This is not exactly what I asked but also helpful.