# "Liftings" of L^\infty functions

Tags: measure-theory, gn.general-topology, fa.functional-analysis

This is motivated by this question: [Is there an inclusion of $L_\infty(G)$ into $C_0(G)^{**}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85411/is-there-an-inclusion-of-l-inftyg-into-c-0g) and Bill Johnson's comments there.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ a Radon measure on $X$.  (We can simplify things to make $X$ compact if we like, so "Radon" becomes much the same a "Borel"; but see below).  Suppose $\mu$ has full support.  Let $M^\infty(X,\mu)$ be the space of all bounded $\mu$-measurable functions on $X$; so $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is the quotient of $M^\infty(X,\mu)$ by the subspace of $\mu$-null functions.
A "strong lifting" $\rho$ is a map $M^\infty(X,\mu) \rightarrow M^\infty(X,\mu)$ which is unital, linear, multiplicative, and such that:

1. $\rho(f)=f$ $\mu$-a.e.
2. if $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. then $\rho(f) = \rho(g)$
3. if $f$ is continuous, then $\rho(f)=f$.

This means basically that $\rho$ picks out a representative of each equivalence class in $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ (and respects continuous functions) and so allows us to genuinely think of $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ as a space of functions.  Very nice...

However, it seems that there is a hidden technicality.  We might ask that each function $\rho(f)$ actually be Borel.  Apparently this is open, even for $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

So the problem is that $\rho(f)$ might genuinely be only $\mu$-measurable.  In the question I link to above, the hope was that we could use $\rho$ to embed $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ into $C_0(X)^{**}$, but that would require us to be able to integrate $\rho(f)$ against any *bounded* Radon measure.  So my question is:

> Which measures can we integrate $\rho(f)$ against (for all $f$)?  Assuming we cannot integrate against all measures, is there a good counter-example to illuminate things?

My reference for all of this is the book "Topics in the theory of lifting" by A. and C. Ionescu Tulcea.  This is an old book; I am not an expert.  Has any progress been made on e.g. the Borel measurability question?

Comment: A modern reference for all things lifting is chaperter 34 in the epos of Fremlin: http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm According to the following, the existence of a Borel lifting is independent of ZFC: http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=shelah%20borel%20liftings&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CGsQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F1994-120-04%2FS0002-9939-1994-1176066-8%2FS0002-9939-1994-1176066-8.pdf&ei=C18QT8bFFs-c-wbSzrXyAg&usg=AFQjCNH-vHWVSdR2KF_XyWmZktRcqPPKJw&sig2=faMFrypFn9b_ymhLswshgA

Comment: On existence of Borel lifting (independent of ZFC) see the first paragraph here http://www.jstor.org/pss/2160244